# Is there an exact answer to this equation?

Tags: problem-solving

$$\frac{1}{x} +\ln(x)\ln(\ln x)=1$$
The solution to this equation is approximately $x \sim 5.13425\ldots$ but is there an exact answer?

Comment: It is *conceivable* that someone might find a combination of "known" constants that happens to be the solution. The interesting thing is that there are no known techniques for proving there is not such a combination. This is in contrast to for example solutions of DE, where there is some machinery for showing there is no solution expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comfort we transform the equation

$\frac{1}{x} +\ln(x)\ln(\ln x)=1\iff e^{\frac{x-1}{x}}=(ln\space x)^{ln\space x}$

The equation to solve is $\phi(x)= e^{\frac{x-1}{x}}-(ln\space x)^{ln\space x}=0$.

There is a clear solution $x=1$ (the domain of $(ln\space x)^{ln\space x}$ is $x\gt 1$ and the limit exists at $x=1$). On the other hand we verify that $\phi(5)$ and $\phi(6)$ have distinct sign so  there is a root of the equation in the interval $[5,6]$ (in fact $\phi(5)\approx0.07459\gt 0$ and $\phi(6)\approx-0.54304$).

For, say $x\gt 2$, both
functions, $ e^{\frac{x-1}{x}}$ and $ (ln\space x)^{ln\space x}$,  are increasing and it is not hard to verify the solution in $[5,6]$ is the only other than $x=1$.

There are several methods of approximation of roots of a trascendental equation. Here without further details, for example, a first step $$5+\frac{(6-5)\phi (5)}{\phi(5)-\phi(6)}=5+\frac{0.07459}{0.07459-(-0.54304)}\approx 5,12076$$  And it is possible a better approximation if the process reiterates.

Answer (score 3):

Denote this number by $\xi$. Then the exact answer is $$\xi={\rm the}\left\{x\in{\mathbb R}_{>1}\biggm|\>{1\over x}+\log x\log(\log x))=1\right\}\ ;$$
after you have *proven* that the set on the right hand side is indeed a singleton.

Comment: This is the most cheaty way ever.

Answer (score 0):

If the $\dfrac1x$ term were missing, letting $x=\exp(e^t)$, we'd be left with $te^t=1$, whose solution is the [$\Omega$ constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant), which is expressible in terms of the [Lambert *W* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). As it stands, however, even the use of such special functions proves futile.